# Is my proof of linear fractional transformations correct?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

a) Prove that the most general $1-1$ conformal map of the upper half-plane onto itself is of the form $$z \to \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$
where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ad-bc =1$.

b) Let $f$ be a $1-1$ analytic function from the plane to itself.  What can it be?  A full explanation from first principles is wanted.

Edit: I think I have a decent proof of part (a), so any hints for part (b) are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: I can show that all *mobious* transformations that map upper plane into itself is $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ad-bc >0$ , but I don't know how to show that only mobious map the upper plane onto itself. is that helpful ?

Comment: just now see your edit. for part b. HINT: think of the type of singularity of $\infty$

Comment: Ya, I'm not too sure of my proof for part a, but I'm going to move on.  That type of classical question can get asked forwards and backwards and in other tricky ways and I have to make sure I haven't made some extra assumptions.   Thanks so much for your hint for part b - I will think of something now :-)

Comment: yes. good start it must be polynomial. you can deduce that from larent series of $f(1/z)$. Now , if you are following you will notice that the degree of the polynomial is the order of the pole at infinity. Now, you just have to show that the order of the pole is 1 , and thus $f(z) = az + b$. or you can just see directely that the only polynom that is a 1-1 , is  $f(z) = az + b$.

Comment: Hi @d_e, sorry - I had deleted my comment, since I didn't think it was a good answer, but I think I was pretty close.  Just that...jumping from "the function has a pole at infinity" to "this implies it must be a polynomial", I realized wasn't correct.  I will try your idea of looking at its Laurent series, but first I want to re-do the problem by looking at 1/(f(z), which is bounded at infinity because of the pole (of order n?) there, and then use Liouville's Theorem and work with the bound to try to show that the function is a polynomial (via Cauchy estimates.)  Thanks a lot! :-)